# file_get_content function for getting the url content

Tags: php

i have decoded json to php array like this :

```
$text = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM";
$last_url = "http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=".$text;
$mp3_url = file_get_contents($last_url);
$var = json_decode($mp3_url, true);
$echo $var['link'];
```

no it shows link in this format :

```
https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=BUuT86WbAYpsj2zvLfkSb2%2BrQxjGl0bRMwnZiGFPR6pXuO1FXOec0doOUcihuH1yTinl2YgaypX3nnsahxx5KA%3D%3D
```

if you open this url a file will download. but on this code it just show s link not the content of that! 
how can i do this ?

Comment: So you want to break youtube's content stealing prevention efforts?

Comment: instead of make fun of question which you even dont know about it, answer it! @arkascha

Comment: I am not making fun at all. I am asking a question. I am sorry if you are annoyed by that, but that certainly is not my fault. I think it makes a lot of sense for anyone considering to help if your desired action is legal or not. No one wants to get caught in legal affairs because of helping someone.

Comment: You need a 2nd `file_get_contents` on the actual download link

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM";
$last_url = "http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=".$text;
$mp3_url = file_get_contents($last_url);
$var = json_decode($mp3_url, true);
echo "<audio src=".$var['link']." controls></audio>";
```

Comment: Now this play the audio on your browser.